# Activating OpenNi depth registration by default

Tags: openni-kinect, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

My problem is the following: I use the openni_kinect package to get rgb/depth feeds from my kinect. I start the ROS nodes for this by using

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

My program needs depth registration to function properly (disabled by default), so far I have enabled this by running

```
rosrun dynamic_reconfigure reconfigure_gui
```

and setting the parameter manually, but it is quickly getting old. Is there a way to turn the depth registration on by default in my roslaunch?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11939/activating-openni-depth-registration-by-default/) by [Per Lenander](https://answers.ros.org/users/1061/per-lenander/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2011-11-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A simple solution is to edit the openni_kinect/openni_launch/launch/includes/device.launch file and add the following param setting to the driver nodelet

```
<param name="depth_registration" value="true" />
```

An alternative solution which works for me is to use the [dynparam command-line tool](http://www.ros.org/wiki/dynamic_reconfigure#dynparam_set) from inside your own launch script, e.g.

```
<node pkg="dynamic_reconfigure" type="dynparam" name="dynparam" args="set /camera/driver depth_registration true" />
```

which avoids the need to edit the launch files in the openni_kinect package.

---

Originally posted by [Andrew Gee](https://answers.ros.org/users/1335/andrew-gee/) with karma: 81 on 2011-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Per Lenander](https://answers.ros.org/users/1061/per-lenander/) on 2011-11-15**:
Thanks! I picked the second alternative since I prefer not to change the ROS files (then my system can work on a clean ROS install)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Another way without using dynamic reconfigure is to use this in your top level launch file:

```
<include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch">
<arg name="depth_registration" default="true" />
</include>
```

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2013-02-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fei](https://answers.ros.org/users/22709/fei/) on 2015-06-12**:
Hello, I want to make sure what I did is right. In side the .launch file that I create, is it should be like followings?